# Converting "numbered" key value XML elements using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a data set (which I have no control over) which has a simple key value structure.  If a table is populated which has n-rows a sample of the output would be:

```
<property>
  <name>Row1_Field1</name>
  <value>Data Value Sample</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>Row1_Field2</name>
  <value>Data Value Sample</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>Row2_Field1</name>
  <value>Data Value Sample</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>Row2_Field2</name>
  <value>Data Value Sample</value>
</property>
```

Is it possible, using XSLT, to convert this into something easier to work with such as the example below?

```
<rows>
  <row>
    <Field1>Data Value Sample</Field1>
    <Field2>Data Value Sample</Field2>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Field1>Data Value Sample</Field1>
    <Field2>Data Value Sample</Field2>
  </row>
</rows>
```

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT2.0 here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <rows>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </rows>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "property[not(substring-before(name,'_')
               =
                substring-before(preceding-sibling::*[1]/name,'_'))]">
  <row>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="inRow" select=
     "/*/property[substring-before(name,'_') = substring-before(current(),'_')]"/>
  </row>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property" mode="inRow">
  <xsl:element name="{substring-after(name,'_')}"><xsl:value-of select="value"/></xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="property"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <name>Row1_Field1</name>
        <value>Data Value Sample</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>Row1_Field2</name>
        <value>Data Value Sample</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>Row2_Field1</name>
        <value>Data Value Sample</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>Row2_Field2</name>
        <value>Data Value Sample</value>
    </property>
</properties>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<rows>
   <row>
      <Field1>Data Value Sample</Field1>
      <Field2>Data Value Sample</Field2>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Field1>Data Value Sample</Field1>
      <Field2>Data Value Sample</Field2>
   </row>
</rows>
```